# Is it possible to determine if a query in MySQL will lock a table?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, is it possible to determine if a query will lock a table before running it? Versions of interest: 5.1, 5.5, 5.6. Storage engines of interest, if that matters: MyISAM and InnoDB.

Thanks!

Comment: Well very very very board question... maybe you should read the MySQL documention instead the answers are in there for sure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Hence you want a testing environment to run queries and see how they behave. Try to make the testing environment as close to production as possible. You can run [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on a query and if it does not use indexes correctly chances are it is going to lock the table when you have a lot of records.